# How to get the iOS Deployment Target value?

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment

For example, the value of `iOS Deployment Target` is iOS 4.3 in one of my Xcode project. How to read that value from the code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this gives back the deployment (i. e. minimal) version or the build SDK version, but there are macros in the `<Availability.h>` header file, using which you can write something like

```
if (__IPHONE_OS_MIN_VERSION_REQUIRED == 4.3) {
    // Code available in iOS 4.3 or later only
}
```

etc.